# Movie where a man's hand is infected by an alien lifeform; the "infection" has kind of a "mini monster head"

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I have this scene from a movie stuck in my head where a man has an alien lifeform infecting his hand. On top of that, I have a vague memory of this being at the end of the movie, and of the "infection" having kind of a "mini monster head".

I already mistook this movie for *The Abyss* (1989) and *Event Horizon* (1997); it's neither of them. The movie is surely not newer than early 2000s. Can someone help me? Does anyone remenber a scene like this from a mid-'80s to early 2000s sci-fi film?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This is, unfortunately, a pretty common trope and also pretty common for a last minute sequel hook, offhand I can even think of a few videogames that have done it.  If there's anything else you can add, it might help narrow it down.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, my memory about it is very vague. But I think that the man shows his hand with the monster head to another one, as if he was hiding it. But I dont rebember if this means a good thing that the "species" is preserved or a bad thing and the man is doomed. The head is kind little and it fits in the close hand, its has kind of a splatter format from wich the little neck and head come from.

Comment: https://futurama.fandom.com/wiki/Brain_Slug

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasyte:_Part_1

Comment: @just_happen_to_know - You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I thought Parasyte was likely too, and you should definitely post it as an answer, but its 2014 release date doesn't line up with the question.

Comment: @SkullDiner have not seen it myself but a quick good search turned up Metamorphosis: The Alien Factor from 1990 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphosis:_The_Alien_Factor it would fit your timeline and the wiki synopsis is a partial match... check it out.

Comment: In the movie *Idle Hands*, a demon possessed the hand of a very lazy young man. However, this was mostly a comedy.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is [Parasyte: Part 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasyte:_Part_1). @ConMan points out rightly though that it came out in 2014, so it doesn't meet the criteria of being an early 2000s movie.

> **Mysterious aliens** called "Parasites" suddenly begin their invasion
> when some of them infect humans by entering their brain. One of them
> attempts to enter the brain of high school student Shinichi Izumi, but
> **resorts to infecting his right hand** after failing to bypass his
> headphones. Thanks to this way of entry, Shinichi retains his human
> consciousness, unlike the other victims. After his initial shock,
> Shinichi befriends the parasite and names him "Migi" (Japanese for
> "right").

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the horror movie "The Gate" from 1987? Near the climax the creatures implant a demon eyeball in the protagonists hand. He is a child though.

Here is the climatic scene where you first see the hand and is full of delightful stop motion animated monsters.